# Can't debug inside custom event

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I've made a custom click event for a custom server control. The control is a button that has a linkbutton and normal button inside it. The event essentially provides a common click event for the link and normal button to fire if they themselves are clicked.

Here is my code:

```
public delegate void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e);
public event ButtonClick Click;

protected virtual void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Click != null)
        Click(sender, e);
}

void butButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OnClick(sender, e);
}

void lbuButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OnClick(sender, e);
}
```

Now on the page where I'm using the control:

```
void sbuSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Cannot debug here! Can't check if event is fired.
}
```

Can I not debug inside my event because it's not firing? If I do a `Response.Write()` inside it I get the text so I presume it's firing. I really need to be able to debug inside my event due to what's going on in the rest of the app. What's going on here? Am I missing something vital?

Comment: Where is your event handler specified? try to do a System.Diagnostic.Debug.Break(), does it work?

Comment: Defined in Page_Init. It does work, it just doesn't debug 'inside' the click function... See comment on post below.

Comment: This is because there are no debug symbols available so the real question is, is your click method within an aspx file or within an cs file?

Comment: It's within a .cs file in a class library. My custom controls are defined entirely programatically. The implementation of the event is within a .aspx page. Hope that's a clear explanation!

Comment: got it. does debugging work in another method in the same file?

Comment: Weirdly enough no, it doesn't. Nor does it seem to work for any page in the project. Even if I add a new page completely removed from my master pages. If I add a System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break() I get a VS debugger window pop up with the message 'An unhandled exception ('Launch for user') occurred in w3wp.exe [5228]. At a loss for what to do now though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Polity's comments, also make sure debugging is enabled in your web config. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your `ButtonClick` event is unncessary here, If both controls just invoke the same click event it may have been easier to do:

```
// hook up both click events of each control to same handler
butButton.Click += DoSomethingOnClick;
lbuButton.Click += DoSomethingOnClick;

private void DoSomethingOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

**Edit**

Think I misread the question initially! Looks like you want to expose a single `Click` event which should be invoked regardless of which button is clicked on the custom control (correct me if I am wrong?).

If that is case then your ButtonClick delegate is unncessary as you aren't using any custom args for your event so you should just be able to write:

```
public event EventHandler Click = new delegate() { };

public void butButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Click(sender, e);
}

public void lbuButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Click(sender, e);
}
```

As for why it's not firing, it's difficult to say without seeing your full code. Can you post the code which you are using to hook up to the `Click` event on the custom control?

Comment: I think it is firing James, it's just that I can't debug inside it! That's what's frustrating me. If I add a System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break() inside my event it is picked up, but it goes to the Click(sender, e); line instead of inside the function!

As an aside, what is the point of the delegate for custom events?

Comment: @Jon - assigning a blank delegate to an event is some compiler magic, saves you having to check if the event is null before invoking it. Hmm seems odd that it won't break in, seems more like an IDE problem than a coding issue if your saying it's outputting Response.Write

Comment: Definitely outputs Response.Write. What's an IDE problem?

Comment: @Jon - IDE is an acronym for **Integrated Development Environment**, in otherwords, a bug with Visual Studio itself. Could be wrong, but if your saying your code works as expected and you just can't break into it then that's what I could expect. What version of your VS are you running?

Comment: @Jon - I was meaning the exact version i.e. the build no. etc. You could use that to google if there are any known issues with that sort of thing with your build.